Displaying hidden element in a div moves the whole horizontal grid row down, how to make it only move the element BELOW the opening element move down?
I am practicing HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I encountered a problem while trying to create a container for company services. Every single service div has a button to show more text which "opens" the div down. I noticed that the whole row in a grid moves down.
There should be 3 service divs in a row and then there should be rows as much as there is service divs remaining and the first element in a horizontal row should be on the left side. I tried to make that when the hidden element is displayed, it would ONLY move down the service div below the opened element and not the whole row.



Please show relevant code see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I see that the items are dupifferent heights. Do you need them to be in rows?

@AHaworth Yes I think it looks more aesthetic if the elements start from the same row when everything is in their original shape when the website is opened.

So, grid won’t work for the expanded case as it will adjust to keep rows.

I would suggest combining the power of grid and flexbox to solve this.
Use a grid with three columns and a single row. Into each grid cell, put a div styled as a flexbox. Then put your service divs into the flexboxes.


document.querySelector('.d1').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.target.classList.toggle('expanded')
})
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.d1>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.d1>div>div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.d1>div>div.expanded {
  height: 40vh;
}

.d1>div>div:hover {
  background: pink;
}
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
    <div>click me</div>
  </div>
</div>




I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I have tried this already. It works fine until the screen is resized and there should be like 2 elements in a row (for example mobilephone view). In this situation there is elements on top of each other even when there is rows with missing elements.

Hmmm. I was going to suggest a solution using the columns property, but the problem with that is that expanding an item causes the columns to rebalance their contents, so it triggers unwanted layout shifts. I presume the same issue would affect the CSS masonry grid, if it ever gets implemented. The only solution I can think of is to rearrange your document structure based on the viewport width, probably using Javascript so you can easily rearrange things on window resize as well as initial load.
